# how to make the a div below the button move down when button is clicked in css

Tags: html, css, animation

Aim: that when send button is clicked for the div below moves down as well meaning they dont overlap eachother.

problem: that when the send button is clicked teh box that animates out overlaps the div below making it look bad. this is what im trying to fix

before being clicked [image: what it looks like at the moment]

after being clicked[image: what it looks like when button is clicked]

```css
.share-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  color: black;
}

.share-link {
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgba(23, 22, 36, 0.4);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.share-link li {
  opacity: 0;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.share-link li i {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.8s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1.2s;
}

.share-link.active li {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.7s;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}

.share-link.active {
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transform: translate(-22%, 23%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.send,
.close {
  color: #1c92d2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.whatsapp,
.mail {
  color: #1c92d2;
  font-size: 19px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  color: black !important;
}

.social-link {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid #1c92d2;
}

.social-link .send {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  animation: sendback 0.3s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.social-link .close {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: rotate-reverse 0.4s ease;
}

.social-link.active {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}

.social-link.active .send {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transform: translate(94%, 94%);
}

.social-link.active .close {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  animation: rotate 0.3s ease 0.7s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(0);
  }
}
```

````html
<div class="share-container">
  <ul class="share-link">

    <li>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab whatsapp fa-whatsapp" alt="Whatsapp"></i>Whatsapp</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ photo.img.url }}" download="{{ photo.img.url }}">


        <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt dnld" type="submit"></i>Download</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope mail" alt="mail"></i>Email</a>


    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social-link">
    <i class="send fas fa-paper-plane" alt="send"></i>
    <i class="close fas fa-times" alt="close"></i>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="email-list">
  <h4>Join our email list to get new updates</h4>

  <div style="background-color: #d9edf7; border-radius: 10px;">
    {% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
    <p class="send-message" style="">{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %} {% endif %}
  </div>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <button type="submit" class="btn button-animate" id="anonimize-btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>


```
````

thank you inadvance any answers are helpful

Comment: Your snippet is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `padding-bottom: 100px;` to the `.share-container` to push contents down when the container is open.

```css
.share-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  width: 350px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

li {
  color: black;
}

.share-link {
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 10px rgba(23, 22, 36, 0.4);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.share-link li {
  opacity: 0;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 7.5px 0 7.5px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.share-link li i {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0.8s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1s;
}

.share-link.active li:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 1.2s;
}

.share-link.active li {
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.7s;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}

.share-link.active {
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transform: translate(-22%, 23%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.send,
.close {
  color: #1c92d2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.whatsapp,
.mail {
  color: #1c92d2;
  font-size: 19px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a {
  color: black !important;
}

.social-link {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 2px solid #1c92d2;
}

.social-link .send {
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  animation: sendback 0.3s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.social-link .close {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0);
  animation: rotate-reverse 0.4s ease;
}

.social-link.active {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%);
}

.social-link.active .send {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transform: translate(94%, 94%);
}

.social-link.active .close {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  animation: rotate 0.3s ease 0.7s;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-reverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(0);
  }
}
```

````html
<div class="share-container">
  <ul class="share-link">

    <li>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fab whatsapp fa-whatsapp" alt="Whatsapp"></i>Whatsapp</a>

    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="{{ photo.img.url }}" download="{{ photo.img.url }}">


        <i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt dnld" type="submit"></i>Download</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope mail" alt="mail"></i>Email</a>


    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social-link">
    <i class="send fas fa-paper-plane" alt="send"></i>
    <i class="close fas fa-times" alt="close"></i>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="email-list">
  <h4>Join our email list to get new updates</h4>

  <div style="background-color: #d9edf7; border-radius: 10px;">
    {% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
    <p class="send-message" style="">{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %} {% endif %}
  </div>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <button type="submit" class="btn button-animate" id="anonimize-btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>


```
````